# Python - Require input from a print function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am testing a print function, where it looks as if the prompt is typing, defined as type()

I would like to store raw input using the type function:

```
from time import sleep
import sys
from random import uniform

def type(s):
    for c in s:
    sys.stdout.write('%s' % c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(uniform(0, 0.3))

name = raw_input(type("What is your name? "))
type("Hello " + name +"\n")
```

This is the output of the code:

> What is your name? None

Input is still allowed from the user, right after 'None', and the output will be correctly printed, without 'None'. Is there a way to circumvent this?

In this prompt I would like to print everything using the type function.

Comment: The problem is that you are passing `type()` to `raw_input`. `type` implicitely returns `None`, since you did not give it an explicit return value. Perhaps try taking `raw_input` inside `type` and *returning the result*. As an aside, the name `type` already belongs to the built-in function `type`, and it is bad practice to shadow it. Choose a different name for your function rather than `type`.

Comment: Python already has a function `type()`. Rename yours to `type_()` or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type("What is your name? ")
name = raw_input()
type("Hello " + name +"\n")
```

There you go. Any function in Python which has no return statement defined, returns a `None` by default - which was showing up on your prompt.

Comment: `name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
type("Hello " + name +"\n")`

Comment: @ASR putting multiline Python code into comments is useless because the indentation gets lost.

Comment: I honestly have no idea why I was trying to complicate this. Thanks for your help. For some reason, I thought that the input would start on a new line.

Answer (score 5):

`raw_input` turns the arg you pass it into a string & uses that as the prompt. You're passing `raw_input` the return value of your type function, and that function returns the default of `None`, so that's why "None" gets printed. So just use your function *before* calling `raw_input` and call `raw_input` without an arg.

BTW, you should *not* use  `type` as a variable or function name because that's the name of a built-in function.

```
from time import sleep
import sys
from random import uniform

def typer(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write('%s' % c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(uniform(0, 0.3))

typer("What is your name? ")
name = raw_input()
typer("Hello " + name + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The default return type for a function is None.  Thus what is happening is that your type function returns at the end of the function with a None which the raw_input then puts into the stdout stream.  Simply having the type function return a blank string would handle the issue:

```
    return ''
```

You might want to use a different function name other then type because type is a builtin and can be useful sometimes.